# PHP Not able to get values from Dropdown box after submitting form

Tags: php, forms, post, field, dropdown

For some reason, I am not able to get the values from my dropdown box and I am trying to figure out why.  Here is my HTML code:

```
<form id="contact" action="reg.php" method="post">
      <select id="State" name="State">
<option value="ST">Choose State</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

 <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
```

However, once it's submitted to reg.php I am not getting any value for $_POST["State"].

Here is my code on the reg.php:

```
$State = $_POST['State'];
echo "Name:". $_POST["FirstName"] . " " . $_POST["LastName"];
echo "Address: <br>". 
$_POST["AddressLine1"]."<br>".
$_POST["AddressLine2"]."<br>".
$_POST["City"]." ".$State.", ".$_POST["Zip"]."<br>";
```

All other fields work just fine, but for some reason, I can't get this dropdown box to give me any data.

Any ideas?

The 2 pages can be found here:

http://alkouri.com/darling/newclient.php

http://alkouri.com/darling/reg.php

You can view the source on each page to see my code..

Comment: `I am not getting any value for $_GET["State"].`=> it's POST method so how you can get `$_GET["State"]`?

Comment: Why you echo out all the posted just like normal, all with doublequotes `"` .. but for state you use a variable and use single quotes. Is there a reason for?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Well, if you would look at his code, you'd see that he used `$_POST`

Comment: @AlivetoDie OP had used $_POST in code but just typed GET in question

Comment: I have copied your code and its working properly

Comment: You code working fine at my end. I am unable to reproduce your problem. Please describe your problem correctly.

Comment: please post complete source html.

Comment: http://alkouri.com/darling/newclient.php

Comment: http://alkouri.com/darling/reg.php

Comment: Those are the 2 PHP scripts.

Comment: I just checked the same code you've posted and it is working.

Comment: I just checked your code. I am getting value of state. I have selected "Florida" from dropdown and its displaying its equivalent value "FL".

Do you mean anything else then this?

Comment: If, as OP's say, your code is OK and `action="reg.php"` is correct then it may be down to spurious hidden characters in reg.php affecting the execution of the script. These hidden chars may removed on copy/pasre to/from Stackoverflow. For more info see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601388/948658  . That said I have only ever had personal experience of these characters generating errors on pre-execution parse.

Answer (score 0):

I used an online PHP beautifer and now it is working...

I don't know what the problem was for me but here is the website I used to fix this:

http://beta.phpformatter.com/